# Program to print permutations of given elements

Tags: c, algorithm

I recently took part in ACM certified programming competition. This is the question which I could not do at that time:

"Given an array of integers having n elements, write a program to print all the permutations."

Please tell me how to do this question. Is there any algorithm to do this kind of questions?

Comment: I tried printing the elements of the array in different arrangements, by changing the order of the elements, but that didn't work and it would not print the n factorial orders.

Comment: are there repeats? is [1,2,3,1] a valid input? if yes - the simple "print all possibilities" won't work, because you need to "remember" which permutations were already printed

Comment: there was no time limit given in the question, but the faster the program, more marks will be awarded.

Comment: the question didn't tell anything about the repeatitions. but if the repeatition is removed, it will be better.

Comment: this site gives a good iterative explanation: https://www.nayuki.io/page/next-lexicographical-permutation-algorithm

Answer (score 27, accepted):

assuming there are no repeats: just change each element with all possible following elements, and recursively invoke the function.

```
void permute(int *array,int i,int length) { 
  if (length == i){
     printArray(array,length);
     return;
  }
  int j = i;
  for (j = i; j < length; j++) { 
     swap(array+i,array+j);
     permute(array,i+1,length);
     swap(array+i,array+j);
  }
  return;
}
```

You can see the code with auxilary functions `swap()` and `printArray()` performing with a basic test case at [ideone](http://ideone.com/nM7YM)

**Bonus**: This is similar to the idea of [fisher-yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle), but in here - intead to swapping the element at `i` with randomly chosen following element - you swap it with all of them - each at a time.

Comment: Why is there a `return;` at the end?

Answer (score 13):

A recursive approach should do fine:

```
If the list is empty
    Return the only possible permutation, an empty list.

Else
    For each element of the list
        Put the element at the first place (i.e. swap it with the first element)
          (If the element is same as the first one, don't swap)
        Recursively find all the permutations of the rest of the list
```

This algorithm won't generate repeated permutations.

Here's a python implementation:

```
def permute(s):
    if len(s) == 0:
        return [[]]

    ret = [s[0:1] + x for x in permute(s[1:])]

    for i in range(1, len(s)):
        if s[i] == s[0]:
            continue
        s[0], s[i] = s[i], s[0]
        ret += [s[0:1] + x for x in permute(s[1:])]

    return ret

s = [0, 1, 2, 3]
for x in permute(s):
    print x
```

The similar thing in C should be like this:

```
void swap(char* str, int i, int j)
{
    char temp = str[i];
    str[i] = str[j];
    str[j] = temp;
}

void permute(char *string, int start, int end)
{
    if(start == end)
    {
        printf("%s\n", string);
        return;
    }

    permute(string, start + 1, end);
    int i;
    for(i = start + 1; i < end; i++)
    {
        if(string[start] == string[i])
            continue;
        swap(string, start, i);
        permute(string, start + 1, end);
        swap(string, start, i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an iterative solution:

First sort the array.

- Find maximum index i  a[i+1]. (if no such index exists there are no more permutations left)

Find maximum index j

Swap a[i] and a[j].

Reverse a[i+1]..a[n-1] and go to step *.

Comment: That's the only really **helpful** answer. It does not help cheating the course, but still gives information.

Answer (score 1):

to get the permutation you have to use recussion and backtracking, you can solve it via brute force also but it becomes complex

```
    void swap(int *x1,int *x2)
    {
        int x=*x1;
        *x1=*x2;
        *x2=x;
    }
    void per(int *arr,int st,int ls)
    {
        int i=0;
        if(st==ls)
        {
            int k;
            for(k=0;k<ls;k++)
            {
                printf("%d ",arr[k]);
            }
        printf("\n");
    }
        else
        {
            for(i=st;i<ls;i++)
            {
                swap(arr+st,arr+i);
                per(arr,st+1,ls);
                swap(arr+st,arr+i);
            }
        }
}

int main()
{
    int arr[4]={1,2,3,1};
    int st=0;
    int ls=4;
    per(arr,st,ls);
}
```