# Enumerate all combinations (cartesian product, abacus, odometer)

Tags: algorithm, delphi, combinatorics

How to implement the following algorithm in Delphi (Object Pascal) in a way that:

- Each alpha numeric item will be a single object (in my case a reference to file strings).
- to be possible to enumerate (to output) each pick state/combination.
- imagine the columns of an abacus; all have the same size (according to its base). I need columns with different sizes. (in my case, sets of file strings with different sizes)

Last EDIT: Please, see [Python intertools implementation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product).

Similar algorithms in other languages: [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058868/finding-all-possible-value-combinations-between-two-arrays?rq=1), [ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15917198/algorithm-to-enumerate-abacus-like-or-the-rule-of-product-combinations), [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9632677/combinatorics-generate-all-states-array-combinations?rq=1), [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10149523/generate-a-combination-of-numbers/10149671#10149671)

### ALGORITHM

Consider the following sets and its members:

> S1 = {a1, a2, a3, a4, a5}
>
> S2 = {b1, b2, b3, b4}
>
> S3 = {c1, c2, c3, c4, c5}

Pick the first member of each set (P = Pick States):

> P1 = {a1, b1, c1}

Then, increment the first until its limit:

> P2 = {a2, b1, c1} P3 = {a3, b1, c1} P4 = {a4, b1, c1} P5 = {a5, b1,
>   c1}

Then, reset the first Set, and increment 'one' the second set;

> P6 = {a1, b2, c1}

Increment the first set again... and so on... reseting the first and the second set for each 'plus one' on third set.

> P7 = {a2, b2, c1}

Regarding the fundamental principle of counting or principle of multiplication, this algorithm would generate 100 pick states/combinations.

> P100 = {a5, b4, c5}

Comment: There are several mathematical concepts related to this construction, such as "cartesian product" and "lexicographical ordering". You have already stated an algorithm that produces the desired enumeration, so it is not very clear what is meant by the "how to" question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've reached a solution using recursive and conditional calls. I've created a record with this structure:

```
  TGridKey = record
    ID : Integer;
    Index : Integer;
    Files : TStringList;
  end;

  TTrialSet = record
    theGrid : array of TGridKey;
  end;
```

With this name in a TForm class.

```
TfRandStimuliSet = class (TForm)

    //...
    lst1: TListBox; 
    dlgOpenPic: TOpenPictureDialog;
private        
    FTrialSet: TTrialSet;
    procedure TfRandStimuliSet.SubSetsMountEngine;
    //...
end;
```

Set Length of the Grid Array:

```
  NumComp := 3;
  SetLength(FTrialSet.theGrid, NumComp);
  for I := Low(FTrialSet.theGrid) to High(FTrialSet.theGrid) do
  begin
    FTrialSet.theGrid[I].ID := I;
    FTrialSet.theGrid[I].Index:= -1;
    FTrialSet.theGrid[I].Files := TStringList.Create;
  end;
```

Put some strings in each 'I' grid:

```
if dlgOpenPic.Execute then
  begin
    if dlgOpenPic.Files.Count > 0 then
    for K := 0 to (dlgOpenPic.Files.Count - 1) do
    begin
     FTrialSet.theGrid[I].Files.Add(dlgOpenPic.Files.Strings[K]);
    end;
    dlgOpenPic.Files.Clear;
  end;
```

Then the procedure:

```
procedure TfRandStimuliSet.SubSetsMountEngine;
var ID: integer; s1 : string;
  procedure AddStmFromGrid(Grid, Stm : Integer);
  begin
    s1 := s1 + ExtractFileName(FTrialSet.theGrid[Grid].Files.Strings[Stm]) + ',';
  end;

  procedure AddTrialFromIndex; //each trial is the current index's
  var I: Integer;
  begin

    for I:= Low(FTrialSet.theGrid) to High(FTrialSet.theGrid) do
      AddStmFromGrid(I,FTrialSet.theGrid[I].Index);
    lst1.Items.Add(s1);
    s1:= '';
  end;

  procedure IndexReset(aGrid : Integer);
  var i : Integer;
  begin
    for  I := aGrid to (High(FTrialSet.theGrid)) do
      FTrialSet.theGrid[I].Index := 0
  end;

  procedure IndexInc(aGrid : Integer);
  begin
    AddTrialFromIndex; //Save
    Inc(FTrialSet.theGrid[aGrid].Index);
  end;

      function MoveGrid(var ID:integer): Boolean;   //begin from right most, the highest grid
      var IDMaxIndex, IDCurIndex, LowID, HighID: Integer;
      begin
        Result := True;
        LowID := Low(FTrialSet.theGrid);
        HighID := High(FTrialSet.theGrid);
        //Application.ProcessMessages;
        if  (ID < LowID) then 
          begin
            //ShowMessage('False');
            AddTrialFromIndex;
            Result := False;
          end
        else
          begin
            IDMaxIndex:= FTrialSet.theGrid[ID].Files.Count -1;
            IDCurIndex := FTrialSet.theGrid[ID].Index;

            if IDCurIndex = IDMaxIndex then  
              begin
                ID := ID - 1;
                Result:= MoveGrid(ID);//moveleft
                Exit;
              end;
            if   (ID < HighID)
             and (IDCurIndex < IDMaxIndex) then 
              begin
                IndexInc(ID);                 //increment/move donw
                IndexReset(ID + 1);           //reset everything on the right
                MoveGrid(HighID);             //move to the most right/next down
                Exit;
              end;
            if  (ID = (HighID))
             and (IDCurIndex < IDMaxIndex) then
              begin
                IndexInc(ID);          //increment/move down 
                MoveGrid(ID)           //next increment/move down
              end;  
          end;
      end;
begin
  ID := High(FTrialSet.theGrid);
  IndexReset(Low(FTrialSet.theGrid));  //0's for everyone
  MoveGrid(ID); //begin from the most right
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are counting.

Each bead is a digit and you're working in base 5 in your example, since each bead can have one of 5 positions.

To determine what position of beads corresponds to a given integer, it is enough to write that integer in the relevant base.  Here's how to do in ruby, for `17`:

```
>> 17.to_s(5).rjust(3, '0')
=> "032"
```

Here I left-padded to 3 beads to be clear where each is, and I'm using a convention that beads begin in position 0, not position 1.

Comment: I am searching for a more general solution, i have edited the title and question based on the "base" constraint considered by your answer.

Comment: The answer came before the question be edited.  ("Delphi" restriction).