# How to generate permutations from 1-10 using arrayLists

Tags: java, math, arraylist

So I am trying to print permutations from 1-10. I am trying to do this using an arrayList but am not sure where to exactly start since i've never coded anything like this

I know the basics of how to generate random numbers but not to a scale like this.

An example output would be this

```
 5   7   8   1   9   6  10   4   3   2
 6   8   1   7   3   4   9  10   5   2
 2   4   9   6   8   1  10   5   7   3
 8   5   4   3   2   9   6   7   1  10
10   3   2   6   8   9   5   7   4   1
 9  10   3   2   1   5   6   8   4   7
 3   8   5   9   4   2  10   1   6   7
 3   2   4   5   7   6   9   8  10   1
 4   1   5  10   8   3   6   2   7   9
 3   5   2   4   1   7   9   6   8  10
```

Comment: This is fairly similar to [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40048131/permutation-of-integers-in-arraylist-java), which consists of generating all permutations of an ArrayList.