# Generate all possible array combinations in C - Optimal Graph Colouring

Tags: c, combinatorics

I need to generate arrays with all possible combinations, like this question I've found here:

[Combinatorics: generate all "states" - array combinations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9632677/combinatorics-generate-all-states-array-combinations)

I'm doing a simple work of **optimal Graph Coloring**, so, I'm trying to generate all possible color combinations (the array represents the color for each node). This code is working but, is also doing unnecessary work. **In this situation, [1, 1, 2] is the same thing of [2, 2, 1], I don't need to test if this is a valid graph again**.

I can't think of anything, but first I would like to know if there's a simple code for doing what I want to.

For now, my code is something like this:

```
void generatearray(int array[], int array_size, int idx){

    int i;

    if(idx == array_size){
        putchar('\n');
        for(i = 0; i < array_size; i++) printf("%i ", array[i]);

    }
    else for(i = 0; i <= 3; i++){
        array[idx] = i;
        generatearray(array, array_size, idx+1);
    }

}
```

And it will print:

```
    [0, 0, 0]
    [0, 0, 1]
    [0, 0, 2]
    [0, 0, 3]
    [0, 1, 0]
    [0, 1, 1]
    ...
    [3, 3, 0]
    [3, 3, 1]
    [3, 3, 2]
    [3, 3, 3]
```

Comment: I guess I don't understand. How is `[1,1,2]` same as `[2,2,1]`?

Comment: [1,1,2] is the same of [2,2,1] because the values of numbers doesn't matter, just the fact that they're different. So, [1,1,2] is also the same thing of [400,400,3] or [0,0,9], for example.

Comment: So `[3, 3, 3]` is the same as `[0, 0, 0]` and shouldn't be in your output?

Comment: Just as `[3,3,2]` is the same as `[3,3,1]` is the same as `[1,1,2]` is the same as `[2,2,1]`. I suspect that no color (`0`) turns out to be the same as any color (`1`-`3`) in the given example.

Comment: And for that matter, `[0,0,1]` is the same as `[0,0,2]` and `[0,0,3]` making for a remarkably short list of arrangements. Especially if `[0,1,0]` is also the same as `[0,0,1]` is the same as `[1,0,0]` (and we now know that `[1,0,0]` is the same as `[0,1,1]` and `[1,2,2]` and `[2,3,3]` and `[3,2,2]`. In other words, does ordering matter in this case or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
void generatearray( int array[], int array_size, int idx = 0, int fixed = 0 )
{
   int i;

   if ( idx == array_size )
   {
       putchar('\n');
       for( i = 0; i < array_size; i++ ) printf( "%i ", array[i] );

   } else {

       for( i = 0; i <= 3; i++ )
       {
          if ( fixed == i )
          {
             fixed++;
             array[idx] = i;
             return generatearray( array, array_size, idx + 1, fixed );
          }
          array[idx] = i;
          generatearray( array, array_size, idx + 1, fixed );
       }
   }
}

int arr[6];
generatearray( arr, 6 );
```

Old broken answer:

```
void generatearray(int array[], int array_size, int idx){

   int i;

   if(idx == array_size){
       putchar('\n');
       for(i = 0; i < array_size; i++) printf("%i ", array[i]);

   }
   else if ( idx == 0 ) {
       array[idx] = 0;
       generatearray(array, array_size, idx+1);
   } else {
       for(i = 0; i <= 3; i++){
       array[idx] = i;
       generatearray(array, array_size, idx+1);
       }

   }
}
```

Comment: Oh, thanks! But actually, this helps my code a little but doesn't solve my problem. It's just using a fixed color for the first array position, but is still generating, for example, [0,3,3] and [0,2,2] and [0,1,1], which is the same thing.

Comment: Now, this is exactly what i'm looking for, thanks! This reduces by 10 times the execution time of my code. You helped my a lot!