# Calculate all possible permutations of an array in C

Tags: c, arrays, permutation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Program to print permutations of given elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9148543/program-to-print-permutations-of-given-elements)

I have tried to find a way how to find all possible permutations of an array in C, but it dind't quite work out.

```
int[] permutations (int a[], int l) {
if (l == 1) {
    return a;
}
int n[l-1];
int i, j, x, d;
for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    printf("i = %d\n", i);
    for (d = 0; d < l; d++) printf("a[%d] = %d\n", d, a[d]);
    x = a[0];
    a[0] = a[i];
    a[i] = x;
    for (j = 1; j < l; j++) {
        n[j-1] = a[j];
    }
    for (k = 0; j < l; k++) {
        a[k+1] = (permutations(n, l-1))[k]
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What errors are you getting ?

Comment: First of all, `int[] permutations (int a[], int l)`, you can't return arrays from functions.

Comment: Are you asking how it can be done? Or what's wrong with your solution? If the first then - Dupe: [Program to print permutations of given elements](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9148543/572670)