# Computing shortest path from complete graph

Tags: c, graph, brute-force, backtracking

I have a matrice NxN where `matrice[i][j]` is a cost of a edge between vertex `i` and `f`j in a non-oriented graph.

What I need to determine is the shortest path containing all of the
vertexes in matrice.

So for input like:

```
0 198 67 368
198 0 131 432
67 131 0 301
368 432 301 0
```

I need to try all posible paths and in this case:

```
0-->1-->2-->3-->0
```

is correct wich gives length 998.

How can I implement this?

Comment: You are describing the Traveling Salesman Problem. There is plenty of material on this problem everywhere.

Comment: Close voters: Why is not not a real question? Is it ambigious? vague? overly broad? rhetorical? (NO! it deals with something very specific, and asks how it could be done)

Answer (score 3):

You are describing the [Traveling Salesman Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem#Exact_algorithms), which is widely studied.

Though there are many ways to approximate a solution - the exact solution requires exponential run-time indeed, and brute force is one option to solve it (in O`(n!)`).

The idea is to generate all possible permutations and evaluate each - and find the minimal.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9148543/572670) for example discusses how to generate all permutations. The same ideas apply to your problem.

There are some possible optimizations that can be done such as [branch & bound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_and_bound) technique - or using a smart [DP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) solution.

Comment: thanks a lot i didnt realize my previous problem changed into traveling salesman problem....i see how it can be donone for one dimensional array but i cant figure out it for matrice