# C - find all the different numbers

Tags: c, arrays, numbers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Program to print permutations of given elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9148543/program-to-print-permutations-of-given-elements)

So, i have number 153 and my program need to output - 135, 153, 315, 351, 513, 531. In other words, all possible numbers. Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Treat it as 3 different characters `'1'`, `'5'`, and `'3'`, then take the combinations of those three

Answer (score 0):

change from int to string, then to an array of chars.  Then use a nested loop.

Comment: ...from string to an array of chars..... really?

Comment: it's a starting point.  Dirty, but gets the job done.  In c the String is already an array of chars.  I am assuming 153 is not the only number they want to do the permutation to.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

void swap(int& a, int& b)
{ int x=a;
a=b;
b=x;
}

void printVector(std::vector<int>& theVector)
{ for (unsigned int i=0; i<theVector.size(); i++)
std::cout << theVector[i] << ",";
std::cout << "\n";
}

void generateAllPermutations(std::vector<int>& toBePermuted, unsigned int nextIndex)
{ if (nextIndex==toBePermuted.size())
{ printVector(toBePermuted);
return;
}
for (unsigned int i=nextIndex; i<toBePermuted.size(); i++)
{ swap(toBePermuted[i], toBePermuted[nextIndex]);
generateAllPermutations(toBePermuted, nextIndex+1);
swap(toBePermuted[i], toBePermuted[nextIndex]);
}
}

void generateAllPermutations(std::vector<int>& toBePermuted)
{ generateAllPermutations(toBePermuted, 0);
}

int main()
{ std::vector<int> theVector;

theVector.push_back(1);
theVector.push_back(3);
theVector.push_back(5);
generateAllPermutations(theVector);
//note: you will have to print out the vector yourself
}
```

Comment: Why put C++ code in a question tagged "C"?

Comment: To point them in the correct direction and give them the answer that is 99% what they asked for is why i wrote it in c++. The person can convert the vector into an array if he/she wants C.

Comment: You're assuming they know C++, without that they'd have to learn about all the things that don't exist in C; like: vectors, "std", "::", even "cout <<" probably looks foreign. It would be more useful to provide pseudo code if you wanted to hint at an answer.

Comment: I gave them the answer. std::cout <<  is c

Comment: `std::cout <<` is C++, `printf(` is C. C and C++ are different languages. In C there are no classes, there are virtual or overloaded functions, there are no strings. C++ code does not compile in a pure C compiler.

Comment: gcc hello.cc -o hello -lstdc++         I have better things to do than argue about this.

Answer (score 0):

This is a small piece of footprint, It may helps you

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv){
  int a,b,c;

  for(a=1; a<4; a++){
    for(b=1; b<4; b++){
      for(c=1; c<4; c++){
      if(!(a==b || a==c || b==c))
        printf("%d%d%d\n",a,b,c);
      }
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```