# permuations of 15 numbers in R

Tags: c, r

I need to compute permuatations of 15 numbers in R ranging from 1 to 15.

```
library(combinat)
#With 1 to 3
permn(3)
#With 1 to 10
options(max.print=factorial(10))
permn(10)
```

Considering the amount of permutations the code above permn(10) takes only 5 minutes and gives me just what I need (but I'm not interested in speed anyway).

However I need to do this with 15 numbers (1 to 15). Unfortunately R returns an error when I try:

```
permn(15)
  Error in vector("list", gamma(n + 1)) : 
  vector size specified is too large
```

**EDIT** *Could this be done in stages?*
I'm using this to reorder a dataset and then do some calculations, so I could do this in stages, for example do the first 300,000 permutations, apply the calculations and then do the next 300,000 permutations etc.In other words, calculate  x permutations then in a loop reorder the dataset columns according to the first permutation, do some calculation, then do the same for the second permutation etc..

Do you know any way around this? Would it be worth using some C code instead? 
I've found a couple of examples (e.g. [1](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-a-c-program-to-print-all-permutations-of-a-given-string/) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9148543/program-to-print-permutations-of-given-elements)) but I have no idea how C works. I can't get it to work with R (probably cause I don't understand what the C code is doing).

I've installed Rccp, Rtools and tried simple cppFunction examples and they work fine, but I haven't been getting anywhere with the string permutations ( When I tried to include the code in the links above I get the error Error in sourceCpp(code = code, env = env, rebuild = rebuild, showOutput = showOutput, : ). Precisely cause I don't understand the C code it's probably pointless to show you the code I ran (it's most likely wrong).

Would anyone be to show me how to run the above (or better if possible) C code from R or do you have any way around it in R?

Many thanks

NOTE: I've reposted this because I changed the number of permutations and moved from strings to numbers.I've also added some details about what I need to do.

Comment: You already asked this question, and it was closed because it's not clear what you actually want to do. Please edit your previous question rather than posting a nearly-verbatim duplicate.

Comment: Do you really need all the permutations stored, or could you just permutate in parts, do some computations, permutate more and so on? If you would just tell where you need the permutations, it would be much easier to think alternatives to this computationally impossible problem.

Comment: You basically got your answer the last time: namely, that there are too many to list them all quickly. But if you provided more details about _why_ you need these permutation (by editing your previous question) we can reopen it and possible suggest some work-arounds.

Comment: Typically generating all permutations of *n* items is used in backtrackig problems, the kind of problems which do not have an efficient polynomial time algorithm and you need to check all possible combinations. For these kind of problems you may use Branch-and-bound, not to search the parts of sample space that surely (or with high probability) the answer is not there.

Comment: Hemmo, I've edited the question. To answer your question, yes I could do this in stages. Many thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 3):

The real issue is that `15!=1,307,674,368,000`. This is just too many lists to iterate over, let alone store in memory.

If we assume for the sake of argument that each iteration of `permn(15)` would take the same time as one iteration of `permn(10)`, and the latter takes 5 minutes in total, you are looking at 3.4 years of computational time.

This is called a [combinatorial explosion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_explosion).

Comment: It's not too much to iterate over in C... but I agree that it's *way* too much to store in memory.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich: Show me some benchmarks for generating `permn(15)` in C, and then we'll talk :)

Comment: let me get back to you... :)

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich: Looking forward to that. Would love to be proved wrong.

Comment: You'll have to wait until I get home tonight because I don't have access to a C compiler at work. But I have an R function that calls some C code and returns one specific permutation, which can generate the first 1 million permutations in an R loop in ~17s on my laptop.  It will be a lot faster if you avoid all the R overhead.

Comment: Whoops, and a lot of that was namespace lookup (the function isn't exported).  It's ~9 seconds if I copy the function to my global environment and avoid `:::`.  Using this method, `permn(10)` takes ~32s but only 4s is spent in `.Call`, so replace 5m with 4s in your calculation that yields 3.4 years of computational time. :)

Comment: Emailed you some benchmarks...