# Generate all binary strings of length n with k bits set.(need to write on C)

Tags: c, binary, permutation

Please help me to solve this task:
Generate all binary strings of length n with k bits set.(need to write on C)
for example:

```
n=5
k=3
11100
00111
11010
01011
**01110
11001
10011
**01101
**10110
10101
```

**  can't generate these permutations

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 10
int main (void)
{
int mas[N]={0},kst,m,n1,z,a,b;
printf("\n\nVvedit` rozmirnist` masyvu: ");
scanf("%d",&kst);
printf("\n\nVvedit` kil`kist` odynyc`: ");
scanf("%d",&n1);
for(m=0;m1;m++)
   mas[m]=1;
for(m=0;m<kst;m++)
   printf("%d",mas[m]);
printf("\n");
for(m=0;m<n1;m++){
   for(z=0;z<(kst-1);z++)
     if((mas[z]==1) && (mas[z+1]==0)){
     a=mas[z];
     mas[z]=mas[z+1];
     mas[z+1]=a;
     for(b=0;b<kst;b++)
        printf("%d",mas[b]);
printf("\n");

      }
  }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist). You might also want to learn what a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) is.

Comment: I am giving some links check it out.And one more thing before asking question here please try to search at least on time on Internet(Google).http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-a-c-program-to-print-all-permutations-of-a-given-string/   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9148543/program-to-print-permutations-of-given-elements

Comment: I see code like this and love C++ more every day: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0dfd78620abdd1ff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved this problem earlier! please find my code below! I hope this will help you out.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int NumberOfBitsSet(int number)
{
    int BitsSet = 0;

    while(number != 0)
    {

        if(number & 0x01)
        {
            BitsSet++;
        }
        number = number >> 1;
    }

    return BitsSet;
}

void PrintNumberInBinary(int number, int NumBits)
{
    int val;
    val = 1 << NumBits; // here val is the maximum possible number of N bits with only MSB set

    while(val != 0)
    {
        if(number & val)
        {
            printf("1");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("0");
        }

        val = val >> 1;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n,k,i;
    int max,min;
    printf("enter total number of bits and number of bits to be set:\n");
    scanf("%d %d", &n, &k);

    min = ((1 << k) - 1); //min possible values with k bits set
    max = (min << (n-k)); //max possible value with k bits set!
    //printf("%d %d", min, max);
    for(i=0; i<= max; i++)
    {
        if(!(i<min))
        {
            if(NumberOfBitsSet(i) == k)
            {
                PrintNumberInBinary(i, (n-1));
                printf("\n");
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thats is great! I know i`m asking too much but can you write this program in recursive way?

Comment: One can use `for(i=min; i<= max; i++)`, and completely remove the if statement `if(!(i<min))`

Answer (score 1):

Your code is a mess ;)

Seriously: first rule when solving a task in code is to write clean code, use sensible variable naming etc.

For tasks like this one I would suggest [using this](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/CodingStyle).

Now to your sample code: it would not compile and it is hard to read what you are trying to do. Formatted and with some comments:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 10

int main(void)
{
        int mas[N] = {0};
        int kst, m, n1, z, a, b;

        /* Read width ? */
        printf("\n\nVvedit` rozmirnist` masyvu: ");
        scanf("%d", &kst);
        /* Read number of bit's set? */
        printf("\n\nVvedit` kil`kist` odynyc`: ");
        scanf("%d", &n1);

        /* m1 is not defined, thus the loop give no meaning. 
         * Guess you are trying to set "bits" integers to 1.
         */
        for (m = 0; m1; m++)
                mas[m] = 1;

        /* This should be in a function as 1. You do it more then once, and
         * 2. It makes the code much cleaner and easy to maintain.
         */
        for (m = 0; m < kst; m++)
                printf("%d", mas[m]);
        printf("\n");

        for (m = 0; m < n1; m++) {
                for (z = 0; z < (kst - 1); z++) {
                        if ((mas[z] == 1) && (mas[z + 1] == 0)) {
                                a = mas[z];            /* Same as a = 1; */
                                mas[z] = mas[z + 1];   /* Same as mas[z] = 0; */
                                mas[z + 1] = a;        /* Same as mas[z + 1] = 1; */

                                /* Put this into a function. */
                                for (b = 0; b < kst; b++)
                                        printf("%d", mas[b]);
                                printf("\n");
                        }
                }
        }

        return 0;
}
```

---

The extensive use of `printf` when one are not sure of what is going on is a precious tool.
This is not a *solution*, (it is basically doing the same as your post, but split up), but a sample of something that might be easier to work with. I have also used a char array as C-string instead of integer array. Easier to work with in this situation.

If you want to use integer array I'd suggest you add a `print_perm(int *perm, int width)` helper function to get it out of the main code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_WIDTH 10

int get_spec(int *width, int *bits)
{
        fprintf(stderr, "Enter width    (max %-2d): ", MAX_WIDTH);
        scanf("%d", width);

        if (*width > MAX_WIDTH) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Bad input: %d > %d\n", *width, MAX_WIDTH);
                return 1;
        }

        fprintf(stderr, "Enter set bits (max %-2d): ", *width);
        scanf("%d", bits);

        if (*bits > MAX_WIDTH) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Bad input: %d > %d\n", *bits, MAX_WIDTH);
                return 1;
        }

        return 0;
}

void permutate(int width, int bits)
{
        char perm[MAX_WIDTH + 1];
        int i, j;

        /* Set "bits"  */
        for (i = 0; i < width; ++i)
                perm[i] = i < bits ? '1' : '0';

        /* Terminate C string */
        perm[i] = '\0';

        fprintf(stderr, "\nPermutations:\n");
        printf("%s\n", perm);

        for (i = 0; i < bits; ++i) {
                /* Debug print current perm and outer iteration number */
                printf("%*s LOOP(%d)   %s\n", 
                        width, "", i, perm
                );

                for (j = 0; j < (width - 1); ++j) {
                        if (perm[j] == '1' && perm[j + 1] == '0') {
                                perm[j] = '0';
                                perm[j + 1] = '1';

                                printf("%s j=%d print\n", 
                                        perm, j
                                );
                        } else {
                                /* Debug print */
                                printf("%*s j=%d skip  %s\n", 
                                        width, "", j, perm
                                );
                        }
                }
        }
}

int main(void)
{
        int width, bits;

        if (get_spec(&width, &bits))
                return 1;

        permutate(width, bits);

        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to list all of the permutations uniquely without doing "iterate and check", you can do something like this:

```
# Move peg x up m using s
# x is negative
# m is positive
def move(x, m, s):
    for i in range(1, m+1):
        s2 = list(s)

        s2[x] = 0
        s2[x - i] = 1

        print(s2)

        if x + 1 < 0:
            move(x+1, i, s2)

# Print all unique permutations of 
# n bits with k ones (and n-k zeros)
def uniqPerms(n, k):
    s = [0 for _ in range(n-k)] + [1 for _ in range(k)]

    print(s)
    move(-k, n-k, s)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from sys import argv
    uniqPerms(int(argv[1]), int(argv[2]))
```

The idea is that you inch the 1's up recursively, so that each movement produces a unique list (since a 1 is now somewhere none was before).

And you said it must be in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

enum { n = 8 };

struct string
{
    char str[n + 1];
};

void move(int x, int m, string s)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= m; ++i)
    {
        string s2 = s;
        s2.str[n + x] = '0';
        s2.str[n + x - i] = '1';
        printf("%s\n", s2.str);

        if (x + 1 < 0)
            move(x + 1, i, s2);
    }
}

void uniqPerms(int k)
{
    string s;
    for (int i = 0; i < n - k; ++i)
        s.str[i] = '0';
    for (int i = n - k; i < n; ++i)
        s.str[i] = '1';
    s.str[n] = '\0';

    printf("%s\n", s.str);
    move(-k, n - k, s);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    uniqPerms(atoi(argv[1]));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
A[n-1]=0;
func(n-1);
A[n-1]=1;
func(n-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Think simple people but please bear with me i love java

//Assume array A is globally defined

void Binary(int n)
{
    if(n<1)
    {
        System.out.println(A);
    }
    else
    {
        A[n-1]=0;
        Binary(n-1);
        A[n-1]=1;
        Binary(n-1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the recursive solution

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


char v[4];
int count = 0;

void printString(){
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        cout << v[i] << "  ";
    }
    cout <<count <<  endl;
 }


void binary(int n){
if(n < 0){
    if(count == 2)
        printString();
}
else{
    v[n] = '0';
    binary(n - 1);
    v[n] = '1';
    count++;
    binary(n-1);
    count--;
}
}



int main(){
binary(3);
return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
int n,k,i,j,a[50];
//lets suppose maximum size is 50
printf("Enter the value for n");
scanf("%d",&n);
printf("Enter the value for k");
scanf("%d",&k);
//create an initial bitstring of k 1's and n-k 0's;
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
if(k>0)    
   a[i]=1;
else
   a[i]=0;
k--;
}
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
if(a[i]==1){
for(j=0;j<n;j++){
if(j!=i&&a[j]==0){
a[j]=1;a[i]=0;
for(k=0;k<n;k++){printf("%d\n",a[k]);}
a[i]=1; a[j]=0;
}}}}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: The code is close unreadable. And, the result is even worse then the one provided from OP. 6 permutations out of 10.

Comment: Great I didn't even tested the code . I just wrote something which I came to my mind. Is it even working!!!

Answer (score -1):

> **If Complexity doesn't matter you can use the following code which are done in java. which will provide the desired output in o(2^n).Here I have find all the combination of 0 and 1 for the given n bits in array of size n.In case of K bit is set I have counted the number of 1 presented is equal to k using countBits() funtion.if so I have printed that array.

```
public class GenerateAllStringOfNBitsWithKBitsSet {
     public static  int a[] ={0,0,0,0,0};
     static int k=3;
     public static boolean countBits(){
        int  y=0;
         for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)   
           y += a[i] &  1 ;

         if(y==k)
             return true;
         return false;
       }
        public static void gen(int n)
        {
            if(n<1)
            {
                if(countBits())
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));

            }
            else
            { 
                 a[n-1]=0;
                 gen(n-1);
                 a[n-1]=1;
                 gen(n-1);
            }
        }
        public static void main(String[] args) {


            GenerateAllStringOfNBitsWithKBitsSet.gen(a.length);
        }

}
```

Comment: It's dosen't answer the question, which was asked and flagged for the language C.

Comment: What is mean by its doesn't answer the question If you have any java editor just run the same code and see the answer and comment your review back ,I am agree that this is not flagged for C.But a person with the given idea can easily convert it  into c.