# Hamiltonian Cycle algorithm

Tags: algorithm, graph, pseudocode, hamiltonian-cycle

I was looking for some hamiltonian cycle algorithms, but I can't find any implementations, not even a single pseudo-code ! I don't even need to output the cycle, just check if the graph has one. The input is a graph with V vertices and E edges. Also, I would like to have an algorithm to check if a graph has a hamiltonian path. I don't need to output the path, just check if it has one. Both should be in polynomial time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is one of the NP-Complete problems.

A brute force algorithm is just creating all permutations and checking if one of them is feasible solution.

Checking the feasibility:

let the current permutation be `v1,v2,...,vn`: if for each `i` there is an edge `v_i -> v_(i+1)` in the graph, and also `v_n->v1` - then the solution is feasible.

---

An alternative is creating a graph `G'=(V,E',w)` where the new edges `E' = VxV` (all edges) and the weight function is:

```
w(u,v) = 1 if there is an edge (u,v) in the original graph
         infinity otherwise.
```

Now you got yourself a [Traveling-salesman problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem), and can solve it with dynamic programming in `O(n^2*2^n)`

Comment: So, that means it can't be solved in polynomial time ? Because I've been told it can be. I don't have to find the cycle, just check wheter a graph has it or not. Could you give me an algorithm or pseudo-code for that brute force approach ? I just need to write a function which returns true if a graph has a hamiltonian cycle.

Comment: I think you a better brute-force algorithm exists, as in your suggestion it will perform a constant `n!` operations, while in some graphs this is a serious overkill (sparse, limited number of neighbours, etc...).

Comment: @clu I suggested how to do it in brute-force, just generate all permutations and check them (explained how to check them). How to generate all permutations is covered in a bunch of questions in SO. PS - since the problem is NP-Complete, it means we do not know if there is a polynomial solution or not, the general assumption is it indeed cannot be done, but it is not proven yet.

Comment: Well, but how would I implement this in C for example ?

Comment: [Program to print permutations of given elements](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9148543/572670)

Answer (score 1):

Unless P = NP, Hamiltonicity can not be decided for general graphs in polynomial time.

An online HCP heuristic exists at http://fhcp.edu.au/slhweb/ where you can upload a graph and test it, but if you want your own function you will either need to write it yourself, or splice in someone else's function. Andrew Chalaturnyk wrote a very good algorithm.