# how to find all permutations of an n digit number without using array or function in c++

Tags: c++, permutation

I am having problems with making this code work the way I want it to. The task is to write a program that prints all the numbers obtained by permutation of digits 1 to n for the entered number n (1 <= n <= 9). The program should also print out how many such numbers are there. I made a for loop that gets the factorial of n so I can get the number of permutation and I combine all of the numbers from 1 to n into a single integer because I think there should be a way to find the permutations that way. So my question is how can I find these permutations?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int n;
    int j;
    int r=0;
    int t=1;
    double f=1;

    cin>>n;

    for(int p=1;p<=n-1;p++){
        t=t*10;
    }

    int u=t;
    //calculates the factorial of n
    for(int o=1;o<=n;o++){
        f=f*o;
    }

    //writes numbers from 1 to n into an integer
    for(int d=1;d<=n;d++){
        j=d*u;
        r=r+j;
        u=u/10;
    }
}
```

Comment: Using consistent indentation would help a lot here, as you're going to get lost in the complexity otherwise.

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble understanding what your expected output could be, if I typed in 8 for n, what would I expect the output to be?

Comment: The expected output would be 40320 for the number of permutations and then all of the permutations of numbers from 1 to 8 (12345678,13245678...).

Comment: Are you aware of [std::next_permutation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/next_permutation/) ?

Comment: Doesn't std::next_permutation require an array?

Comment: May be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9148543/program-to-print-permutations-of-given-elements

Comment: https://www.topcoder.com/blog/generating-permutations/

Comment: @Binary, no, it doesn't. You can pass it iterators to the beginning and end of a string, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, read the number into a string. You can read it into an integer and after that write it to a string, if you want to make sure the format is correct:

```
int number;
if (!(std::cin >> number)) {
    // Failure to read number. Do some diagnostic.
    throw std::runtime_error("invalid number");
}

// Number read successfully. Write it to a string.
std::string s = std::to_string(number);
```

The first permutation is the sorted permutation of all digits. This one is easy to obtain using `std::sort`.

```
std::sort(s.begin(), s.end());
```

Finally, use `std::next_permutation` to get the other permutations. Once it gets the last one, it will return `false` and exit the loop.

```
int n{0};
do {
    ++n;
    std::cout << s << '\n';
} while (std::next_permutation(s.begin(), s.end()));

std::cout  << "Number of permutations: " << n;
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2aadab18f82cb8c2)